# Using a second Excel workbook as a table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Wondering if it's possible to use a second workbook as a table to grab matching data similar to a vlookup without using the formula.

Example:
Workbook 1 I want to fill in Column R (Port Code) by looking at Column S (Port City) by using Workbook 2 which has a list of Cities in column D and the Port code I want to fill in workbook 1 in column A.

I know I could use a Vlookup but trying to avoid doing that if I can.
I was thinking of something like this but this only appears to look at the first line of the second worksheet. Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
Dim lr As Long, lr1 As Long, i As Long
Dim LineMaster As Workbook
Dim ls As Worksheet
Dim di As Workbook
Dim td As Worksheet

Set td = di.Worksheets(1)
Set ls = LineMaster.Worksheets(1)
lr = ls.Range("I" & ls.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        For i = 2 To lr
            If ls.Range("S" & i).Value Like "" Then
               ls.Range("R" & i).Value = ""
               
            ElseIf ls.Range("N" & i).Value = Left(td.Range("D" & i).Value, 4) Then 
                   ls.Range("N" & i).Value = td.Range("A" & i).Value
               
        Else
        End If
        Next i
```

Comment: Yes. There are many ways. What you are doing is infinitely slower than doing a VLOOKUP.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be. Only reason I was trying to avoid the vlookup is because it requires altering the format of the spreadsheet I'm referencing. But sounds like that still might be easier than setting up some sort of reference loop.

Comment: Have you considered using `=INDEX()` and `=MATCH()` formulas together or an `=XLOOKUP`? Might avoid reformatting your workbook (only assuming without seeing it)

Comment: Basically, you have two options. Either write the columns to arrays and create a loop etc. or create an `INDEX/MATCH` (`VLOOKUP`) formula, write it to the resulting column and do a 'copy/paste values'. There are usually only 4 columns yet your code has 5 (`S,R,N and D,A`). Could you clarify and/or post the Excel formula you currently have in the resulting column? Also, what is the 'Left-business' all about?

Comment: @VBasic2008 thanks for the response. The formula I ended up using was `=IF(RC[1]="""","""",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[1],5)&""*"",tmp!C1:C2,2,0))` which looks at the column with the port city, takes the first 5 letters and vlookups back to my reference sheet "tmp" (that was copy and pasted from the workbook I originally wanted to use) against port cities there and inputs the city code via the vlookup otherwise leaves it blank.

Comment: @SamuelEverson to be honest I have never used `XLOOKUP` I'll have to take a look, didn't even know that was a formula lol. I'll need to look that one up. I had considered using `INDEX` and `MATCH` but I believe they would need very specific criteria in the matching process and not all of these port cities (which are entered by hand) are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understood your request, but I think you want to do a partial search. In this case, the `Instr` might be helpful.
I don't think using two workbooks is useful but let's do it your way. Here's what I would go with:

```
Sub PartialSearch()

Dim lr As Long, lr1 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim LineMaster As Workbook
Dim ls As Worksheet
Dim di As Workbook
Dim td As Worksheet

Set LineMaster = ThisWorkbook 'Workbook to fill
Set ls = LineMaster.Worksheets(1) 'Worksheet to fill
Set di = Workbooks.Open(your_workbook) 'Indicate the path of the workbook
Set td = di.Worksheets(1)

lr = ls.Range("S" & ls.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row of the column S (where cities are already mentioned)
lr2 = td.Range("D" & di.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lr
            For j = 2 To lr2
                If ls.Range("R" & i).Value = "" Then 'If the cell in column R is empty
                    If InStr(1, ls.Range("S" & i).Value, td.Range("D" & j).Value) > 0 Then 'Then the macro looks for a partial search in the other workbook
                        ls.Range("R" & i).Value = td.Range("A" & j).Value 'If the value is found, then the port code is written (change the column A if needed)
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        
        
End Sub
```

Depending on the size of your workbook, this approach might not be the most effective. If it's too time consuming, you could go with `.Find`.

Comment: I totally agree the way I have to do it is totally inefficient but my hands are tied. if I had my way everything would just have stuff like this exported into a SQL table and then setup a query from that. Thanks for this I'll give it a try and see if works. Happy New Year!